# How can I use Dropbox for iPhone and iPad backup and not iCloud?

Tags: iphone, backup

Both devices drove me nuts until I caved and increased my iCloud storage for backup.  I couldn't find a way to change default to my Dropbox account.  Please tell me how....

Answer (score 1):

Tubedogg is right; there is no way to directly back up to your dropbox.  However, if you have your heart set on *storing* your backups in dropbox, you could back up to your computer and use a sym link to route iTunes' backups to a dropbox folder

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use Dropbox as a backup target for a backup of your entire device (or to restore from it, for that matter). You can either use iCloud or your computer.